# If a BCH is mined do those coins go against the total 21 million supply

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoin-cash, bitcoin-gold

I wanted to find out when a fork happens does that mean there are double the amount of total coins added to the max original total of 21 million

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, they are not added with respect to the original limit. Under the bitcoin accepted rules there will be a total of 21 million coins, and under BCH accepted rules there will be a total of 21 million coins.

Answer (score 2):

The Bitcoin blockchain and the Bitcoin Cash blockchain are now two separate chains.  Even though they both originated from the same genesis block (and several years of common blocks), they have now forked and can never be reunited.  This means you should look at them as two separate currencies, each with their own similar but different rules.

As such, the Bitcoin blockchain can only ever support 21M BTC, and the Bitcoin Cash blockchain can only ever support 21M BCH.  So that does not mean anything has doubled; that would mean there can be 42M BTC...which isn't true.  It means there can be 21M BTC, and also 21M BCH.  Just like there may be X number of euros and X number of dollars, but that doesn't mean there are 2X euros or 2X dollars.  They are separate.

Comment: Thank you for that explanation, that was excellent. So each time there is  a Hard Fork a new Currency is formed and can use the open source code to create a max total of 21 million Coins . This explains why some are calling BTC Original and BCH the Fake or vice versa.

Comment: @Jcoin Yes, the new currency is formed in parallel with the old (original) BTC. Although community can agree that old BTC code should be deprecated (perhaps of some bug in the original code) so the new fork becomes original bitcoin. Also the new coin can have a different total number of coins if this is enforced with the fork.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is doubled. Its a copy of the original chain with a few changes.
So there are two chains with 16mil/21mil coins atm.